# Incrementing a variable value through a pointer inside a child fork

Tags: c, pointers, fork

This code below is supposed to execute external programs passed as arguments to the main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc ,char* argv[])
{
    int e =0;
    int* f=&e;
    printf("%p\n",f);
    pid_t p ;
    for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        p=fork();
        wait(NULL);
        if(p==0)
        {
            printf("\n---------------------\n");
            execvp(argv[i],&argv[i]);
            printf("erreur \n");
            (*f)=(*f)+1;
            printf("%d\n",*f);
            printf("%p\n",f);
            exit();

        }
    }
    if(p>0)
    {
        printf("erreurs: %d \n",*f  );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program also aims to show how many errors occured. However, the variable e=0 remains 0 even if the pointer *f pointing to its address was incremented inside the child fork.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: After a fork, the child receives a copy of the memory of the parent. So changes to variables do not propagate back to the parent.

Comment: The whole point of processes is that they have separate address spaces. If you want shared memory between processes, you've got to set it up before forking (see mmap), and then make sure your e variable is within that shared memory block.

Answer (score 4):

When you call [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) the process is duplicated. The parent and the child each have their own private memory maps, their own set of all variables. It's not possible for one process to change the value of another process variables.

If you want to share data between two processes you should use other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods, like for example [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).